# java SocketException: unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, socketexception

i am having an issue with Java HttpURLConnection. I am sending an audio file (midi format) from the client to the server. This part works perfectly fine. After that i want to use that file on the server side for an algorith i wrote. This algorithm analyzes midi files for genre and played instruments. When analyzing the midi file, i get back an object of a self-written class StringArrayUndString. In this class there exists simply a String[] (for the played instruments) and a String (for the genre). The program works completely fine, if i just send the midi file to the server and send a response 200 code. However, if i want to analyze the midi file after receiving it from the client and then send back the analyzed data in the form of a StringArrayUndString-object, i get the following error: `java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server` and not even the response code is shown. The file is still transfered correctly. Enough talking for now, here is the code:

```
private static void sendPOST() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        final int mid = 1;
        final String POST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/musiker/hörprobe?mid="+mid;
        final File uploadFile = new File("C://Users//Felix Ulbrich//Desktop//EIS Prototype MIDIs//Pop//IWantItThatWay.mid");
        String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        String CRLF = "\r\n";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        URLConnection connection = new URL(POST_URL).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
        connection.setReadTimeout(0);
        try (
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);
        ) {
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"binaryFile\"; filename=\"" + uploadFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Length: " + uploadFile.length()).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(uploadFile.getName())).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
            writer.append(CRLF).flush();
            Files.copy(uploadFile.toPath(), output);
            output.flush();
            int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == ((HttpURLConnection)connection).HTTP_OK){
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(input);
                Object object = ois.readObject();
                if(object instanceof StringArrayUndString){
                    StringArrayUndString Daten = (StringArrayUndString)object;
                    for(int i = 0; i<Daten.array.length; i++){
                        System.out.println("Instrument: "+Daten.array[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Genre: "+Daten.string);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Response code: ["+ responseCode + "]");
        }
    }
```

This is the Client-side.

```
System.out.println("Ich bin am Anfang!");
                    int hörprobenzaehler = 0;
                    Statement hoerprobenzaehlen = myConn.createStatement();
                    String hoerprobensql = "select MAX(hpid) from hörprobendaten where musiker_mid='"+musikerid+"'";
                    ResultSet anzahl = hoerprobenzaehlen.executeQuery(hoerprobensql);
                    while(anzahl.next()){
                        hörprobenzaehler = anzahl.getInt("max(hpid)");
                    }
                    String CRLF = "\r\n";
                    int fileSize = 0;
                    System.out.println("Ich erzeuge das File!");
                    String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "C://root//m"+musikerid+"hp"+(hörprobenzaehler+1)+".mid";
                    File f = new File(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                    if (!f.exists()) {
                        f.createNewFile();
                    }
                    System.out.println("File erzeugt!");
                    InputStream input = t.getRequestBody();
                    String nextLine = "";
                    do {
                        nextLine = readLine(input, CRLF);
                        if (nextLine.startsWith("Content-Length:")) {
                            fileSize = 
                                Integer.parseInt(
                                    nextLine.replaceAll(" ", "").substring(
                                        "Content-Length:".length()
                                    )
                                );
                        }
                        System.out.println(nextLine);
                    } while (!nextLine.equals(""));
                    byte[] midFileByteArray = new byte[fileSize];
                    int readOffset = 0;
                    while(readOffset < fileSize){
                        int bytesRead = input.read(midFileByteArray, readOffset, fileSize);
                        readOffset += bytesRead;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Array gelesen!");
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = 
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED));

                    bos.write(midFileByteArray, 0, fileSize);
                    System.out.println("Datei geschrieben!");
                    InstrumentIdentifier II = new InstrumentIdentifier(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                    DynamicIdentifier DI = new DynamicIdentifier(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                    MusicalTextureIdentifier MTI = new MusicalTextureIdentifier(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                    MidiAnalyzer analyzer = new MidiAnalyzer(II, DI, MTI);
                    StringArrayUndString Daten =analyzer.analyze();
                    System.out.println("File analysiert!");
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    OutputStream output = t.getResponseBody();
                    System.out.println("Response Header ist raus!");
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
                    t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
                    oos.writeObject(Daten);
                    System.out.println("Response Object ist raus!");
                    oos.flush();
                    oos.close();
                    System.out.println("Fertig!");
```

This is the Server side.

On the Server side i used some System.out.println commands, so i would see where my program stops working and it seems, it stops right after the `System.out.println("Datei geschrieben!");`. If anyone knows a solution, please let me know :). Thank you very much.

Greetings, Gizpo

Comment: You have to flush (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#flush()) the `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: I am doing so, but maybe a bit too late i do it after i try to analyze the midi file..... i will try it out, thanks :)    EDIT: I tried it out, it's still not working :(